# make input type=text disabled or readOnly with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

hello everyone i try to make a bunch of text inputs to *read Only* or disabled using *JavaScript* 
i know you can do it with *read Only* attribute but i wanna do it with JavaScript .my problem is it doesn't work in an external JavaScript file but when i put it inside html file it works here is the code

```
var myInpts=document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
  for(var i=0;i<myInpts.length;i++)myInpts[i].disabled=true;
  alert(myInpts.length);
```

Comment: Can you post the html file code that you are currently using?

Comment: If your javascript not work in external file, that reason is onReady ( because your webpage must be completely load in dom ). you can put your external file in footer of HTML code and test it again.

Comment: Well where is the script tag?

Comment: Did you get any errors? If so, please post it as well! Your code should work if the elements exist and the DOM is loaded...

Comment: @MohammadrezaYektamaram i did put <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script> in the footer as u said and it worked thank you

Comment: @FZs i didnt get any errors but it worked finally when i did put <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script> in footer

Comment: @KhalidElfatouaki Then, it's better to place the `script` tag back, and place your code inside this: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{ /* place code here */ })`, it will make your code more easy to debug, and defers your script until the entire DOM is loaded. See @Bibberty's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event listener for `DOMContentLoaded` this will ensure your code executes when the DOM is ready.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']").forEach(input => {
    input.disabled = true;
  })
});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Test">
<input type="text" value="Test">
<input type="text" value="Test">
<input type="text" value="Test">
<input type="text" value="Test">
<input type="text" value="Test">
<input type="text" value="Test">
```

If you want to toggle based on a click for example:

```js
const toggleInputs = () =>   document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']").forEach(input => {
    input.disabled = !input.disabled;
  })

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  toggleInputs();
});

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  toggleInputs();
});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Test">
<input type="text" value="Test">
<input type="text" value="Test">
<input type="text" value="Test">
<input type="text" value="Test">
<input type="text" value="Test">
<input type="text" value="Test">
<button>Toggle</button>
```

Comment: well the code example  is wrong.....

Comment: @epascarello I corrected the event. Used click at first, my bad.

Comment: You've written `document.addEventListener('click', ...)` instead of `document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', ...)`, so I've corrected it. Why are you always trying to add a click listener to document? 

Comment: @FZs take a look here: [Event Delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) Whilst I agree you might want to scope it. Perhaps wrap the buttons in a `div` the principle is sound. I am assuming in the code there is more than the one button.

Comment: I know how the event delegation works, I've just thought that you've added the button, because you didn't want that any click on the entire page (including the input boxes) to toggle the *disabledness*...

Comment: @FZ no fair play, one button could definately be assigned lol.